# Why Does reduce Stop After One Account Number?

Tags: clojure

Something is wrong with the way I wrote the gen-sim-map function. It stops after one account number, and the last number in the vector. I am wondering what I am doing wrong. I could solve the problem by applying repeat to the function, but that seems wrong to me.

Here is the data and the call; the function defs are below that.

```
(def acct-nums (gen-acct-nums 5))
#'ba1-app/acct-nums

ba1-app=> acct-nums
[10000 10001 10002 10003 10004 10005]

ba1-app=> (gen-sim-map acct-nums)
{10005 [\W 160.12]}

(defn random-trans 
    [] 
    (nth avail-trans (.nextInt random (count avail-trans))))

(defn random-amount
    []
    (float (/ (.nextInt random (count (range 1 10000))) 25 )))

; Generate an account number. The range is arbitrary to make it look a real bank account #.
(defn gen-acct-nums [range-end-idx]
    (vec (range 10000 (+ 10000  range-end-idx 1))))

(defn gen-sim-map [acct-nums]
    (reduce
        (fn [sim-map one-acct-num]
            (let [trans (random-trans )
                  amt   (random-amount )]
                { one-acct-num (vector trans amt) } ))
        {}
        acct-nums))
```

Comment: I don't see where you're changing the accumulator (`sim-map`) anywhere .

Comment: Yes, I forgot that, and that is why I saw the last value, right? The others were processed but not accumulated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you're not changing the accumulator. I'd expect to see something like

```
(defn gen-sim-map [acct-nums]
    (reduce
        (fn [sim-map one-acct-num]
            (let [trans (random-trans )
                 amt   (random-amount )]
                (assoc sim-map one-acct-num (vector trans amt)) )) ; <---
        {}
        acct-nums))
```

or similar.